Second Case milestone within an entitlement is not getting tagged automatically
Whenever I create a new case the trigger does auto triggering of entitlement tagging and the first case milestone criteria starts. Now if it violates then a field update of escalation level field is set to escalated. Now the second case milestones has criteria similar to that of first case milestone in addition to that of escalation level field equals escalated. The second milestone does not get tagged automatically even after the field updates. Now if I manually update the case record then the second case milestone record is created. What could be the root cause and how can we fix it?
Tried below steps:-

Tried checking unchecking re-evaluate workflow rules still did not resolve the issue

Tried changing the start time to Entitlement process as well still is not working
In other environment I'm not facing this issue.
PS:- Thanks in advance!
